# increasing density of beam light in volume rendering

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

I am simulating in animation a film projector with a light beam in volumetric.  On the pic attached you can see that the beam is quite light.. I want to densify the beam more like an intense light coming from the lens..  I attach the blend file http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45259 and a pic showing my current state..
I have tried to balance volume scatter and  absorption but with no satisfactory result.. Can you suggest something 
Thanks

Comment: Hi. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend uploads.

Comment: Try https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-atmospheric-lighting-blender/  Start a new file and make a simple setup work. You'll see you don't need the "domain" object or volume absorption.

Comment: Thanks.; did not think about increasing the light intensity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using scattering you need increase the intensity of the light.

[image]

[image]